# Using jQuery.get() to load content from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make one request to load content from another page then search through that content and pull out the information I need. I've been trying to use jQuery.get() to do this but can't get it working.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$.get('/category/page-2/', function(data) {
  var theContent = $(data).find('#newWrapper img').attr('src');
  theContent.appendTo('#container'); // this isn't inserting the url string

  console.log('the content: ' + theContent); // theContent returns undefined
}, 'html');
```

I got jQuery.load() working but I need to get multiple bits of information out of the returned document and don't want to make a request for each one. This worked fine:

```
$( ".related-product" ).eq(0).load( "/category/page-2/ #newWrapper img" );
```

Comment: what is the value of `data`? are you sure the element `'#newWrapper img'` exists in `data`? also `theContent` is not a jQuery object for you to call `theContent.appendTo()`

Comment: could you do `console.log(data)` and post it here

Comment: dont use HTML at last ,better to use json

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird: Maybe he has no influence on the content of the remote site, if he has, json would definitly be a better approach.

Comment: @ArunPJohny @YuliamChandra: `console.log(data)` returns a string containing the html of the external page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery.get('/category/page-2/',
{
    ajax: true
}, function (data) {
    data = jQuery(data);
    var theContent = jQuery('#newWrapper img', data).attr('src');
    theContent.appendTo('#container'); // this isn't inserting the url string
    console.log('the content: ' + theContent); // theContent returns undefined

});
```

Comment: This throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined `

Comment: Did you check, is your selector `$('#newWrapper img')` works fine on your page `'/category/page-2/'` ?

Comment: @ServerHalilov: yep, `$('#newWrapper img')` works fine on `'/category/page-2/'`